# Looping through observable array and update calculated value

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have an Observable array and I'd like to be able to have a public value that would contain a computed value that comes from the array's contents.

```
@Injectable()
export class PaymentsProvider {

  total: number = 0;

  private payments = new BehaviorSubject(<Payment[]>[]);
  payments$: Observable<Payment[]> = this.payments.asObservable();

  constructor() {

    console.log("init payments service")
    this.total = 0
    this.payments$.subscribe( payments => {
       for (let payment of payments) {
         this.total += payment.amount
       }
    })    
  }
}
```

This works, and I can call `this.paymentsService.total` from other components, however if I leave a page component and navigate back, the value **doubles** even though the `payments` array has not changed.

Should I calculate this a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `this.total = 0;` inside your subscribe's callback

```js
    
    this.payments$.subscribe( payments => {
       this.total = 0
       for (let payment of payments) {
         this.total += payment.amount
       }
    })
```

Comment: This solved it.  Could you explain why I need to do that?  Am I subscribing multiple times?  I just want to make sure I'm setting things up properly

Comment: the callback function of your subscribe is called every time  your payements changes so you have to recompute total and reset it to 0 in the begining of the computation.